# Closed form for $\sum_{p=0}^{i} \binom{a}{p} \binom{b}{i-p} \binom{b+c -(i-p)}{m-i}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

$a,b,c,i,m$ are all integers. Does there exist a closed form for $\sum_{p=0}^{i} \binom{a}{p} \binom{b}{i-p} \binom{b+c -(i-p)}{m-i}$?

Comment: CAS says: $\binom{b}{i} \binom{b+c-i}{m-i} \, _3F_2(-a,b+c-i+1,-i;b-i+1,b+c-m+1;1)$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, what does the notation $F_2$ stand for?

Comment: generalized hypergeometric function